# Blank PHPSESSID remains blank

Tags: php, yii

If I create an empty COOKIE PHPSESSID and then login with corrected username/password the PHPSESSID remains blank...

is it normal ?

Thanks

PS: I think PHPSESSID should be re-generated in this case

Comment: Show some code, are you calling session_start(); at the beginning of each script?

Answer (score 0):

The server create the PHPESSID cookie itself when a session is started, you should avoid to manupulate this cookie as it is the reference of the session in the server. To avoid user to send you illegal characters or even an empty PHPESSID cookie (that will generate a warning error) you can look at this function in this php.net note: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#82957

Comment: I agree with you, but for security reasons (hacking)                         I seek for a solution to prevent it

Comment: you can prevent javascript (XSS) to use this cookie by setting up the 'httponly' option in the setcookie function (or in http.conf in the apache configuration) but, you can't prevent the user to create it's own cookie as it is in the client side
Put some code of your problem if this is not answering your question